# Mongoose error when deploying on Heroku nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, heroku

I have completed a project and trying to deploy on heroku. I am using Reactjs frontend and express Nodejs with mongoose and mongodb in the Backend. It works on localhost but when I run Build it and try to deploy it on heroku it gives an application error.

Here is my backend connection code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express')
const session = require("express-session")
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const zomatoRoutes = require('./Routes/zomato')
const paymentRoutes = require('./Routes/payments')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const passport = require("passport")
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');


const uri = process.env.MONGO_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/zomato';

console.log(uri,'this is the mongo Atlas uri if connected using that !!!')

const options = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    dbName:'zomato1'
}

const connectDB = async () => {

    await mongoose.connect(uri, options ).then(() => {
        console.log('mongo connected')
    }).catch( e => console.log(e))
}


connectDB().then(() => {
    
    app.listen( process.env.PORT ||5252 , () => {
        console.log("express app is up and running on port 5252");
    })
})
```

I also have mongo session store the mongoose session when user logs in

```
app.use(session({
    secret: "this is unambigous secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { maxAge: 24*60*60*1000 },
    store   : MongoStore.create({ 
        client: mongoose.connection.getClient(),
        dbName:'zomato1',
        ttl: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60
     })
    
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

It gives me **MongoNotConnectedError: MongoClient must be connected to perform this operation** error when I try to deploy using

```
git push heroku master:main
```

full error tail :

```
mongodb+srv://vishal_torne_22:********@db-first-hernode.zu6btrs.mongodb.net/<DBNamecomeshere>?retryWrites=true&w=majority this is the mongo Atlas uri if connected using that !!!
2022-07-31T11:19:34.581869+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:367
2022-07-31T11:19:34.581876+00:00 app[web.1]: throw new error_1.MongoNotConnectedError('MongoClient must be connected to perform this operation');
2022-07-31T11:19:34.581877+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-07-31T11:19:34.581877+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-31T11:19:34.581878+00:00 app[web.1]: MongoNotConnectedError: MongoClient must be connected to perform this operation
2022-07-31T11:19:34.581878+00:00 app[web.1]: at getTopology (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:367:11)
2022-07-31T11:19:34.581881+00:00 app[web.1]: at Collection.createIndex (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:258:82)
2022-07-31T11:19:34.581881+00:00 app[web.1]: at MongoStore.setAutoRemove (/app/node_modules/connect-mongo/build/main/lib/MongoStore.js:147:35)
2022-07-31T11:19:34.581881+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/connect-mongo/build/main/lib/MongoStore.js:128:24
2022-07-31T11:19:34.581882+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
2022-07-31T11:19:34.581882+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-31T11:19:34.581882+00:00 app[web.1]: Node.js v17.9.1
2022-07-31T11:19:34.703486+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-07-31T11:19:34.791551+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I am using Mongoose to connect the Mongodb, It works on localhost without heroku but when I deploy it using heroku, It asks me to use MongoClient. Is it a requirement to use mongoClient on Heroku 20 stack, I also get warning to upgrade to new Heroku version, I tried to upgrade heroku using npm upgrade heroku to the specifed version it shows successful but again rolls back to heroku 20 stack.

here's what I tried but researching the previous answers :

1. I added on my mongodb atlas the whitelist 0.0.0.0/0 (includes you current IP address)
2. I tried to make the mongoose code async so that it connect firsts the database then app listens to the port.
3. changed the engine version so that it supports latest node and npm version on Heroku like:

```
{
"version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "17.x",
    "npm":"8.x"
  }
}
```

Is it a requirement to use MongoClient on heroku 20 stack ? as the Error shows... and why it is showing error on Mongoose.connect()

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

As you say it runs fine in your local environment, the issue may be fixed by adding `process.env.MONGO_URL` to the [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) of your application, as the issue may originate when Heroku tries to connect to your MongoDB, but does not achieve this connection due to an invalid url that is stored in an `env` variable on your local device.

Comment: I have already set vars on Heruko using their website thats is MONGO_URI and alse set its value to the mongo db atlas srv string. Thanks

Comment: Have also console.logged the uri its showing me the uri srv i.e srv string

Comment: @VishalTorne happy to help in any way. I really do not recognize this very specific error,  sorry if I cannot help that much :(